# Big clock on whole screen in centos-7

Tags: centos, tmux, clock

I was going to write command `tmux detach` but I accidentally pressed some other key/ key combinations and saw a big clock on the whole terminal. There was just time printed and nothing else.

I don't know whether it appeared because of a package I installed unknowingly or because of a native Linux/centos package.

The most relatable thing that I could say I found was is the image present in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/526281/666221).

The text font was very much similar to the font present in the above-mentioned image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tmux` has a `clock-mode` that can be accessed with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.  So, by default it can be toggled on/off by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.  See `man tmux`.

Comment: I've accepted it as the answer. Sorry, I can't upvote it because I don't have enough reputation here.